# Debugging Mobile add ins

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are trying to enable our outlook 365 add in on Outlook mobile. After making necessary changes to the manifest and enabling the add in and testing on android, we notice that although simple test apps are loading fine, the full fledged app is having some issues that we have not seen in desktop or OWA modes.

We are currently blocked on debugging this further, because:

- on iOS simulator, we are not able to install outlook mobile - there is no App store access inside the simulator and the ipa files are not available.
- on Android emulator, we are able to install the app (using the hockey app link provided earlier), but Android WebView debugging is not enabled for the app - so we are not able to connect to laptop chrome and make progress on the issues.
- we tried vorlon.js, but due to some network issues (VPN based), its not able to capture the app session correctly. Its also very buggy and has performance issues.

Is there any way to proceed further here? Would it be possible to obtain an outlook apk file with debugging enabled?

Comment: Any update on this? Is the below method worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Android - just connect the real Android device with your development Windows machine using USB cable and run Chrome F12 tools for debugging. See [Get Started with Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)